# Remove text from Image attr('src');

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the src of an image, however im fetching the thumbnail image src and need to manipulate the src to get the fullsize image:

Jquery:

```
$(this).attr('src');
```

That gets me: `http://local/images/_w/image_jpg.jpg`

I need to replace: `_w/` to get the fullsize image, how can i do this in jQuery?

Comment: Unfortunately jQuery can't do this.... but JavaScript can! :)

Comment: @Felix what do you mean jQuery can't do this ??

Comment: @mcgrailm: I want to say that jQuery is merely a library for JavaScript and that not every problem is a jQuery problem. But people seem to think that jQuery is different from JavaScript and that it is doing something magic. Anyway, jQuery does not provide any string manipulation methods so you cannot replace a string with jQuery.

Comment: @Felix ahh I see your point replace is in fact a javascript function not a jQuery functio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="swap">Swap</a>
<img class="thumb" src="http://local/images/_w/image_jpg.jpg" />

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".swap").click(function(){

        var src = $(".thumb").attr("src");
        src = src.replace("/_w", "");

        $(".thumb").attr("src", src);
        alert($(".thumb").attr("src"));
    });

});
```

Here is an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ttzu/)

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#fullImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_w/', '???'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.replace('_w/','whatever you want');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var temp $(this).attr('src');

var NewURL = temp.replace("_w/", "derp");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('src').replace("_w/", "");
```

This is assuming you want to just remove the `_w/` part of the path. Otherwise replace the empty string with whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of javacripts excellent string manipulation functions like `replace`:

```
var src_fullsize = $(this).attr('src').replace('/_w/','/');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of getting jQuery to do it, as Javascript already has a [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function built in.

```
var v = $(this).attr('src').replace('_w','whatever');
$(this).attr('src', v );
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
var og_source = $(this).attr('src');
var replacement_text = "_big"
$(this).attr('src',$og_source.replace('_w/',replacement_text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `_w` with the string that contains the size and then set attribute `src` again.

```
$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_w', '100x100'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
var newImg = $('#myId').attr('src').replace('_w/','');
$('#myId').attr('src', newImg);
```